# How to add models in a custom add admin page?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

In Django Admin I have a Product model that has foreign keys of other models.
The default add Product form didn't display the name of the choices so I create custom forms to display the names.

In the default add Product page I could add a model to use for the product I am adding.
I would like to have that ability as well as see the names of my choices.

Also I use a foreign key that has a pair of unique attributes (name and version). Currently I am setting choices to

```
REVISIONS = [(revision, revision.name) for revision in Revision.objects.all()]
```

I would like to be able to see both the name and the version, something like this

```
REVISIONS = [(revision, revision.name + revision.version) for revision in Revision.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add a **unicode**(self) method and the admin menu displayed names and the default form could be used which has the ability to add a foreign key to be used.